# How to show foreignkey attributes django admin fields?

Tags: python, django

This question is similar with others but it is a different one actually ! So, I have 3 models such as (I have deleted some unnecessary things for shorter code):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_content = models.TextField()
    category_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.category_title


class Classes(models.Model):
    classes_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    classes_content = models.TextField()
    classes_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.classes_title

class Subjects(models.Model):
    subject_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject_content = models.TextField()
    subject_class = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.subject_title
```

So let me give an example. I can have 2 categories and in those categories I can have "same named" classes. Lets think about maths is a class for both categories. When I want to add a new subject to maths I see 2 same named maths in admin page. So I want to know which one belongs to which category in admin page. So I can add my subject to right class.

```
class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = ('subject_title', 'subject_content', 'subject_class',)
```

So in this picture (Subjects = Konular) I am adding a new subject. I will have a foreign key to Class. However I have same name for classes that are coming from different categories. So in this dropdown how can I know which class belongs to which category ?

[image]

Comment: Besides the question, your naming convention is not good, stick with pep8, classes names should be singular (because an instance is one object) and inside `Subject` class, why do the attributes start with subject as a prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, This should work.

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    classes_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    classes_content = models.TextField()
    classes_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Subjects(models.Model):
    subject_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject_content = models.TextField()
    subject_class = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.subject_title} - {str(self.subject_class)}"
```

Comment: I think I need to make this question clearer. Because 2 answers are kinda same and that is not what I am asking :)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've read it 3 times and this is what I've understood, edit and I'll answer it after I understand it correctly

Comment: Show your templates and how does this dropdown get populated please

Comment: this is default django admin page. I dont have my own template

Comment: @omerS my solution holds, try it

Comment: I have tried but nothing changes. Did you get my question with the edited one ?

Comment: Okay, yes this is the proper and easiest way to do it. But not the exactly thing I was looking for :)

Comment: Customize as needed, Be sure not to spam queries there as this can slow admin interface in websites with big databases.
Have a nice day.

Comment: and please, remove the prefixes, make names singular, this will change your life, use pycharm and it will automatically suggest these things

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
class KonularAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = ('subject_title', 'subject_content', 'subject_class', 'get_classes_category_title')

    def get_classes_category_title(self, obj):
         subject_object = Subjects.objects.get(id=obj.subject_class)
         return str(subject_object.classes_category.category_title)
```

- It returns the category title name

Comment: It didnt work actually. Or i didnt get how to use that function

Comment: append `get_classes_category_title` in fields set

Comment: yes i have tried it but didnt work. (Unknown field(s) (get_dersler_kategori_title) specified for Subjects)

Comment: it also says in the documentation like this but gives the error above

Comment: Use `subject_object` object, I Update solution try that one..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__str__()` method to change the string representation of an object:

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
  subject_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  subject_content = models.TextField()
  subject_class = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

def __str__(self):
  return f"{self.subject_title} - {self.subject_content} - {self.subject_class}"
  # shorter version:
  # return f"{self.subject_title[:10]} - {self.subject_content[:10]} - {self.subject_class[:10]}"
```

Check it with:

```
>>> print(Subjects.objects.first())
```